# Как при помощи Ajax и PHP вытащить из БД url и вставить его в src тега img?

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

**Здравствуйте.** 
Обычно я пишу сайты без сложных серверных кусков и структур, но в этот раз волею случая был вынужден работать с незнакомой для меня сферой.

Необходимо реализовать альбом, в котором фотографии будут подгружаться из БД, когда пользователь скролит до последнего фото. Ввиду своей некомпетентности, решил использовать знакомую платформу jQuery для отслеживания положения скроллинга и позиции последнего элемента, а так же для отправки ajax запросов на сервер. Как раз на ajax запросах и возник конфликт между сервером и клиентом.

**Алгоритм:** 
 Когда пользователь заходит на страницу, сервер отправляет ему 20 фотографий. При прокрутке на последнее фото отправляется еще 10 фотографий и так пока они не кончатся.

**Проблема:**
 Во время загрузки фото происходит некая ошибка, из-за которой в src фотографий остается поле: (unknown).

[image: в src картинки поле unknown]

```js
var id = 1;

var getLink = function(id) { //Получаем url очередного id
  var url = "";
  
  $.ajax({
    url: "source/php/album/getLink.php", //Получаем url
    type: "POST", //Скрыто от пользователя
    date: {
      id: id
    },
    success: function(date) {
      url = date;
    },
    error: function(date) {
      console.log(date + "::error_2");
    }
  });
  
  return url;
}

//Приведен фрагмент программы с генерацией первых 20 фото.

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

  var url = getLink(id); // Вот тут возникает интересная ситуация
                         // Мы получаем линк из бд, но ajax, похоже, не ждет, когда сервер ответит, и присваивает нулевую ссылку. (Могу ошибаться).
  $(".album").append('<img class="album_photo" src = "' + url + '" name = "id_' + id + '">');

  id++;
}
```

```html
<section class="album">
  <img class="album_photo" src="source/images/ajax-loader.gif">
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

P.S: Если выводить url в console.log, то он отображается.

Comment: Функция getLink() завершит свою работу ДО того, как выполнится ajax запрос, т.к. он асинхронный. Нужно либо установить флаг синхронной работы ajax, но тогда вся страница подвиснет на время выполнения запроса, либо добавлять картинки после успешного (success) выполнения ajax запроса.

Comment: Каким образом я могу добавить картинки только после успешного выполнения? Ведь именно такой вариант и требуется.

Comment: Если устанавливать циклом while - высокая нагрузка, отправлять поток в сон - Преувеличенное ожидание. Может быть вы знаете другие пути решения такой задачи? У меня ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы навели меня на мысль как можно поправить ситуацию.

Comment: То есть нужно просто соответствующую логику добавить в 
    success: function(date) {
      url = date;
    }

Comment: Все так Ruslan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно по-другому реализовать. Цикл for перебирает не дожидаясь ответа от сервера.

1. При загрузке страницы показать первые 20 фото.
2. При скролле отправлять текущую страницу (сначала это будет 1 страница, далее 2, 3, ...).
3. На сервере вытаскивать из базы фото порциями, по 10 шт на страницу например.

Рабочий пример из 2 файлов:

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="images js_images">

    </div>

    <button type="button" class="js_next" data-page="1">Следующая страница ...</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Вставка изображений в html
        var renderImages = function(images) {
            var html = '';

            // подготовка html
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                html += '<img src="' + images[i] + '">';
            }

            // вставка фото в html с классом js_images
            $('.js_images').append(html);
        };

        // Вытащить изображения
        var getImages = function(page) {
            $.ajax({

                // можно вставить свой url
                // source/php/album/getLink.php?page=
                url: "/server.php?page=" + page,
                type: "GET",
                success: function(res) {

                    // если сервер выдает в json формате нужно подготовить его для дальнейшей обработки
                    // если нет, то просто var images = res;
                    var images = JSON.parse(res);

                    // Если не пусто
                    if (images.length) {

                        // увеличить страницу на 1
                        var currentPage = +$('.js_next').attr('data-page');
                        $('.js_next').attr('data-page', currentPage + 1);

                        // отобразить изображения
                        return renderImages(images);
                    } else {
                        alert('Изображений нет!');
                    }
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err + "::error_2");
                }
            });
        };

        // Нажатие на кнопку Следующая страница ...
        // Можно вызывать функцию getImages(page); при скролле вниз
        $('.js_next').on('click', function() {

            // возьмем текущую страницу
            var page = $(this).attr('data-page');

            // получим фото и вставим в html
            return getImages(page);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

server.php

```
<?php

// если страница передана и не пуста
if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])) {

    // Это пример массива с изображениями
    // У вас тут будет запрос в БД, в котором будет передаваться номер страницы $_GET['page']
    // обработка и приведение данных к такому виду:
    $array = array(
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/',
        'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/Dummy-Text/'
    );

    // вывод в json формате
    echo json_encode($array);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Если вы не против, я воспользуюсь вашим кодом.

Comment: @hanji Да, конечно!