# Как сделать подобное Ajax обновление?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, вёрстка, frontend

Ребят как сделать простое обновление фотогалереи? Не каких прелоудеров и прочих штучек. Просто нужно чтобы при прокрутке вниз подгружалось 10 фоток, при еще одной прокрутке еще 10 фоток и т.д.
Я слаба во фронтенде, пожалуйста мальчишки очень нужна помощь :(
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Посмотри здесь ответ на твой вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/694359/11236

Answer (score 0):

Это уже серверная часть, когда изначально показывается n картинок, а при прокрутке идет проверка на достижение конца страницы и, в случае, выполнения условия, посылается ajax-запрос на получение следующей порции, с проверкой на то, а есть ли у нас еще что показывать, иначе можно бесконечно подгружать последние элементы. По сути та же постраничная навигация, только с помощью скролла.